# Shared session vs. session with default configuration

Tags: objective-c

What are the differences between the two `session` objects created in these two different ways:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
```

and

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you are using them, they're functionally very similar.

That having been said, using `sharedSession` doesn't give you the ability to customize the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` (e.g., tweak the cache, custom headers, etc.), nor use the delegate-based rendition of `NSURLSession`. See the “limitations” section of the `sharedSession` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1409000-sharedsession).

But if you don't need those features, feel free to use `sharedSession`, as it is easier.

---

A word of caution: The shared session returns the same instance every time. This means that you never have to “invalidate” it (nor should you ever do so).

However, the exact opposite is true for a session that you create yourself with `sessionWithConfiguration`. If you create your own session, you bear responsibility for cleaning up when you are done with it (generally with [`finishTasksAndInvalidate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1407428-finishtasksandinvalidate)). If you repeatedly create new session objects and neglect to invalidate them, you will leak memory.

To avoid this overhead and hassle, you should generally create a session once, and only once, and save it in a property for future usage. Avoid unnecessarily repeatedly creating your own session objects.

Answer (score 1):

[NSURLSessionConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLSessionConfiguration)

session with basic set of properties that control various policies on a sessionwide basis. These properties are set on a session at the time of its creation and cannot be changed later. If you need to change these policy properties, create a new session with a modified session configuration.

[sharedSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSession/sharedSession)

Returns a shared singleton session object.

Please review Apple Documents first as these are the source of very information.

Comment: I've read the docs and the two code snippets in the question look the same to me. The doc for `sharedSession` simply says "The shared session uses the currently set global NSURLCache, NSHTTPCookieStorage, and NSURLCredentialStorage objects and is based on **the default configuration**."