# URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default) vs URLSession.shared

Tags: swift, azure-notificationhub

I am following notificationhub tutorial and their code is as follows. They are using session as follows. I wonder why they are not using `URLSession.shared` instead. Both are working, but wonder what is the logic behind.

```
private let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

(self.session.dataTask(with: request) { dat, res, err in
   // do some stuff
}).resume()


// URLSession.shared approach
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { dat, res, err in
    // do some stuff
}).resume()
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25392272/7098650) by @Rob they both are similar in functionality, the configuration could be used for delegation purposes (I've converted the Old Objective-C answer in the link into Swift below).

As you're using them, they're functionally very similar. But using `shared` doesn't give you the ability to customize the `URLSessionConfiguration` (e.g. tweak the cache, custom headers, etc.) nor use the delegate-based rendition of `URLSession`. But if you don't need those features, feel free to use `shared` as it's easier.